# How to specify servlet-api version in Gradle?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, gradle, spring-boot

I found a way to specify the target servlet-api version and use Tomcat 7 in maven: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-tomcat-7
It's done by setting these properties in pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.56</tomcat.version>
    <servlet-api.version>3.0.1</servlet-api.version>
</properties>
```

But I can't figure out how to set it up in Gradle build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, overriding a property to set the version of a dependency only works in Maven. You can achieve the same effect in Gradle using a resolution strategy. The following will cause all of Boot's Tomcat dependencies to version 7.0.56:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency {
            if (it.requested.group == 'org.apache.tomcat.embed') {
                it.useVersion '7.0.56'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the process list, it's still running tomcat 8. However, I don't care about the tomcat version much. Mostly I care about the servlet API version. Is it possible to change the Servlet-API version similar way?

Comment: Tomcat 8 requires Servlet 3.1 so trying to use 3.0 with it won't work

Comment: How did you tell from the process list that Tomcat 8 was still being used? Are you deploying to a standalone container? Running `gradle dependencies` will let you confirm the versions that you build's now using.

Comment: It's possible to see the classpath in the running process and see what jar versions are used. Well, I gave up with spring-boot already, because I'd had other problems with it. I tried the change in a small isolated project and I actually saw it picked up tomcat7, but it didn't work for me in a subproject as a part of our system. Maybe it's something wrong with our gradle scripts, I don't know, but I don't feel like figuring it out these days, sorry, maybe some time later I'll give it a try, as I like the spring-boot concept.

Comment: The bottom line is the change seems working in a minimal project, so I'll mark it as the best answer. Though it didn't fix the problem for my particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ext {
    tomcatVersion = "3.1.0.RELEASE"
    servlet-apiVersion = "build@master.org"
}
```

Comment: "servlet-apiVersion" is not valid syntax.. However, I don't think the gradle plugin will pick up those values from ext, cause I grepped the plugin database and didn't find any mentions regarding tomcat or servlet-api version. It looks not implemented.